# Android Application Error "Unfortunately App has Stopped" - Radio Buttons

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, textview

I'm relatively new to the StackOverFlow so if I make a mistake in formatting something here or other newbie mistakes, please pardon me and feel free to edit my post so as to make it clear. I will make sure not to repeat those mistakes.

Anyhow, I am working on developing an android application (VERY BASIC) for my computer science class in high-school and I am relatively close to finishing. I'm just really frustrated because one aspect of my app keeps causing the app to crash and give the error "Unfortunately App has Stopped". I was wondering if you guys could kindly help me out.

Basically, what I meant for it to do is that the person enters their name in the textfield (EditText) and then they select 1/2 of the radio buttons (either English or French greeting) and then the label(TextView) below is supposed to show as Hello + "their name input" or Bonjour based on the radio button selection. However, after the input, the app just crashes when I click the "Display!" button. I appreciate any and all help that I can get from you all :)

Kindly find below the java and xml file:------------------------------------

```
    import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
    private EditText text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /** Mouse Listener AKA Called soon as user clicks the Send button */
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void showAboutMessage(View v){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Grade 12 Student @ Bluevale Collegiate Institute!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } 


    private boolean flipsided = false;
    public void flipImage (View view){
        ImageView portrait = (ImageView)
        findViewById (R.id.faceImageView);

        if(flipsided){
            portrait.setImageResource(R.drawable.normal);
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Yes, that's me in NYC :)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        flipsided=!flipsided;
    }

    @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
    public void onClick(View view){
            RadioButton engButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
            RadioButton frenchButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);

            if(text.getText().length() == 0){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter a valid name!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            TextView label = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.JLabel);

            if(engButton.isChecked()){
                label.setText("Hello" + text.getText().toString().toUpperCase());
                frenchButton.setChecked(false);
                engButton.setChecked(true);
            }else{
                label.setText("Bonjour" + text.getText().toString().toUpperCase());
                frenchButton.setChecked(false);
                engButton.setChecked(true);

        }
    }
```

And then this is my XML file: ------------------------------------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <CheckedTextView
        android:id="@+id/checkedTextView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/my_name"
        android:textSize="27sp" />

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkedTextView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/faceImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ratingBar1"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:onClick="flipImage"
        android:src="@drawable/normal" />

    <CheckedTextView
        android:id="@+id/checkedTextView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:text="@string/rate" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/faceImageView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/aboutMeButton"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"
        android:text="@string/button_send" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/faceImageView"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/aboutMeButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkedTextView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="showAboutMessage"
        android:text="@string/about" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

SECOND XML FILE -------------------------------

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".DisplayMessageActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/enter_name" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button13"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="@string/button_print" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" >


    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/JLabel"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:text="@string/radio_button2"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="@string/radio_button1"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/JLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="@string/JLabel"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my logcat file:

```
06-18 21:13:04.859: D/AndroidRuntime(1826): Shutting down VM
06-18 21:13:04.859: W/dalvikvm(1826): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4d14908)
06-18 21:13:04.859: E/AndroidRuntime(1826): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-18 21:13:04.859: E/AndroidRuntime(1826): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method onClick(View) in the activity class com.example.bci_snsapplication.DisplayMessageActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'button13'
06-18 21:13:04.859: E/AndroidRuntime(1826):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3584)
06-18 21:13:04.859: E/AndroidRuntime(1826):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
06-18 21:13:04.859: E/AndroidRuntime(1826):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
06-18 21:13:04.859: E/AndroidRuntime(1826):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
06-18 21:13:04.859: E/AndroidRuntime(1826):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-18 21:13:04.859: E/AndroidRuntime(1826):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-18 21:13:04.859: E/AndroidRuntime(1826):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
06-18 21:13:04.859: E/AndroidRuntime(1826):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-18 21:13:04.859: E/AndroidRuntime(1826):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-18 21:13:04.859: E/AndroidRuntime(1826):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-18 21:13:04.859: E/AndroidRuntime(1826):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-18 21:13:04.859: E/AndroidRuntime(1826):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-18 21:13:04.859: E/AndroidRuntime(1826): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: onClick [class android.view.View]
06-18 21:13:04.859: E/AndroidRuntime(1826):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
06-18 21:13:04.859: E/AndroidRuntime(1826):     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:915)
06-18 21:13:04.859: E/AndroidRuntime(1826):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3577)
06-18 21:13:04.859: E/AndroidRuntime(1826):     ... 11 more
06-18 21:13:04.899: E/DropBoxManagerService(1192): Can't write: data_app_crash
06-18 21:13:04.899: E/DropBoxManagerService(1192): java.io.IOException: Can't mkdir: /data/system/dropbox
06-18 21:13:04.899: E/DropBoxManagerService(1192):  at com.android.server.DropBoxManagerService.init(DropBoxManagerService.java:582)
06-18 21:13:04.899: E/DropBoxManagerService(1192):  at com.android.server.DropBoxManagerService.add(DropBoxManagerService.java:185)
06-18 21:13:04.899: E/DropBoxManagerService(1192):  at android.os.DropBoxManager.addText(DropBoxManager.java:272)
06-18 21:13:04.899: E/DropBoxManagerService(1192):  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$12.run(ActivityManagerService.java:8545)
06-18 21:13:04.909: W/ActivityManager(1192):   Force finishing activity com.example.bci_snsapplication/.DisplayMessageActivity
06-18 21:13:05.219: W/Trace(1192): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-18 21:13:05.219: W/Trace(1192): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
```

MORE LOGCAT DETAILS---------------------------------------------------------

```
06-18 22:47:25.029: W/Trace(1663): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-18 22:47:25.029: D/ExchangeService(1663): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand, startingUp = true, running = false
06-18 22:47:25.029: W/Trace(1663): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-18 22:47:25.029: W/ActivityManager(1193): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
06-18 22:47:25.036: D/ExchangeService(1663): !!! Email application not found; stopping self
06-18 22:47:25.036: W/Trace(1663): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-18 22:47:25.056: W/ActivityManager(1193): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
06-18 22:47:25.056: W/Trace(1663): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-18 22:47:25.056: E/ActivityThread(1663): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@b5036390 that was originally bound here
06-18 22:47:25.056: E/ActivityThread(1663): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@b5036390 that was originally bound here
06-18 22:47:25.056: E/ActivityThread(1663):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
06-18 22:47:25.056: E/ActivityThread(1663):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
06-18 22:47:25.056: E/ActivityThread(1663):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
06-18 22:47:25.056: E/ActivityThread(1663):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
06-18 22:47:25.056: E/ActivityThread(1663):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-18 22:47:25.056: E/ActivityThread(1663):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-18 22:47:25.056: E/ActivityThread(1663):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-18 22:47:25.056: E/ActivityThread(1663):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-18 22:47:25.088: E/StrictMode(1663): null
06-18 22:47:25.088: E/StrictMode(1663): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@b5036390 that was originally bound here
06-18 22:47:25.088: E/StrictMode(1663):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
06-18 22:47:25.088: E/StrictMode(1663):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
06-18 22:47:25.088: E/StrictMode(1663):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
06-18 22:47:25.088: E/StrictMode(1663):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
06-18 22:47:25.088: E/StrictMode(1663):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
06-18 22:47:25.088: E/StrictMode(1663):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
06-18 22:47:25.088: E/StrictMode(1663):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
06-18 22:47:25.088: E/StrictMode(1663):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
06-18 22:47:25.088: E/StrictMode(1663):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
06-18 22:47:25.088: E/StrictMode(1663):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
06-18 22:47:25.088: E/StrictMode(1663):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
06-18 22:47:25.088: E/StrictMode(1663):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-18 22:47:25.088: E/StrictMode(1663):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-18 22:47:25.088: E/StrictMode(1663):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-18 22:47:25.088: E/StrictMode(1663):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-18 22:47:25.088: E/StrictMode(1663):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-18 22:47:25.088: W/ActivityManager(1193): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@b51f0d58
06-18 22:47:25.096: E/ActivityThread(1663): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@b50238c8 that was originally bound here
06-18 22:47:25.096: E/ActivityThread(1663): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@b50238c8 that was originally bound here
06-18 22:47:25.096: E/ActivityThread(1663):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
06-18 22:47:25.096: E/ActivityThread(1663):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
06-18 22:47:25.096: E/ActivityThread(1663):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
06-18 22:47:25.096: E/ActivityThread(1663):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
06-18 22:47:25.096: E/ActivityThread(1663):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
06-18 22:47:25.096: E/ActivityThread(1663):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
06-18 22:47:25.096: E/ActivityThread(1663):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
06-18 22:47:25.096: E/ActivityThread(1663):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
06-18 22:47:25.096: E/ActivityThread(1663):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
06-18 22:47:25.096: E/ActivityThread(1663):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
06-18 22:47:25.096: E/ActivityThread(1663):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
06-18 22:47:25.096: E/ActivityThread(1663):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
06-18 22:47:25.096: E/ActivityThread(1663):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-18 22:47:25.096: E/ActivityThread(1663):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-18 22:47:25.096: E/ActivityThread(1663):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-18 22:47:25.096: E/ActivityThread(1663):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-18 22:47:25.096: E/ActivityThread(1663):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-18 22:47:25.108: E/StrictMode(1663): null
06-18 22:47:25.108: E/StrictMode(1663): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@b50238c8 that was originally bound here
06-18 22:47:25.108: E/StrictMode(1663):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
06-18 22:47:25.108: E/StrictMode(1663):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
06-18 22:47:25.108: E/StrictMode(1663):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
06-18 22:47:25.108: E/StrictMode(1663):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
06-18 22:47:25.108: E/StrictMode(1663):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
06-18 22:47:25.108: E/StrictMode(1663):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
06-18 22:47:25.108: E/StrictMode(1663):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
06-18 22:47:25.108: E/StrictMode(1663):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
06-18 22:47:25.108: E/StrictMode(1663):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
06-18 22:47:25.108: E/StrictMode(1663):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
06-18 22:47:25.108: E/StrictMode(1663):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
06-18 22:47:25.108: E/StrictMode(1663):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
06-18 22:47:25.108: E/StrictMode(1663):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-18 22:47:25.108: E/StrictMode(1663):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-18 22:47:25.108: E/StrictMode(1663):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-18 22:47:25.108: E/StrictMode(1663):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-18 22:47:25.108: E/StrictMode(1663):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-18 22:47:25.108: W/ActivityManager(1193): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@b539b310
06-18 22:47:25.436: W/Trace(1964): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0



06-18 22:49:05.357: E/ActivityThread(1663): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@b5085b08 that was originally bound here
06-18 22:49:05.357: E/ActivityThread(1663): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@b5085b08 that was originally bound here
06-18 22:49:05.357: E/ActivityThread(1663):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
06-18 22:49:05.357: E/ActivityThread(1663):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
06-18 22:49:05.357: E/ActivityThread(1663):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
06-18 22:49:05.357: E/ActivityThread(1663):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
06-18 22:49:05.357: E/ActivityThread(1663):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
06-18 22:49:05.357: E/ActivityThread(1663):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
06-18 22:49:05.357: E/ActivityThread(1663):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
06-18 22:49:05.357: E/ActivityThread(1663):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
06-18 22:49:05.357: E/ActivityThread(1663):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
06-18 22:49:05.357: E/ActivityThread(1663):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
06-18 22:49:05.357: E/ActivityThread(1663):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
06-18 22:49:05.357: E/ActivityThread(1663):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-18 22:49:05.357: E/ActivityThread(1663):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-18 22:49:05.357: E/ActivityThread(1663):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-18 22:49:05.357: E/ActivityThread(1663):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-18 22:49:05.357: E/ActivityThread(1663):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-18 22:49:05.357: E/StrictMode(1663): null
06-18 22:49:05.357: E/StrictMode(1663): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@b5085b08 that was originally bound here
06-18 22:49:05.357: E/StrictMode(1663):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
06-18 22:49:05.357: E/StrictMode(1663):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
06-18 22:49:05.357: E/StrictMode(1663):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
06-18 22:49:05.357: E/StrictMode(1663):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
06-18 22:49:05.357: E/StrictMode(1663):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
06-18 22:49:05.357: E/StrictMode(1663):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
06-18 22:49:05.357: E/StrictMode(1663):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
06-18 22:49:05.357: E/StrictMode(1663):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
06-18 22:49:05.357: E/StrictMode(1663):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
06-18 22:49:05.357: E/StrictMode(1663):     at
```

Comment: Post a stack trace from logcat. It's much easier to find the cause of the crash that way.

Comment: where is your radiobuttons in your xml?

Comment: @Karakuri how would I do that? Sorry it's only my 5th day using eclipse and developing android apps.

Comment: @Raghunandan oh that was in a different XML file, I'll attach that on there right now!

Comment: Then that's the problem. You can't use `Views` in another `Layout`

Comment: @codeMagic Its just a different class, but its still within the same layout subgroup

Comment: I am running the app again on the emulator with the logcat showing. Soon as i get the data, ill post it here. Sorry for the delay, the app takes like 3-4mins to load onto the emulator.

Comment: " Its just a different class, but its still within the same layout subgroup " not if its a different `xml` file unless you use the `<include>` tag to include it in the `Layout` that you inflate with `setContentView()`

Comment: @ironman2295 you can findViewById of the current view hierarchy set to the activity. So you cannot initialize radiobutton if you don't have it in the layout set to the activity

Comment: @codeMagic Okay, but if I move the radio button, that changes my app. Currently, my app runs and then the user clicks a button to open a separate window in which the radio buttons exist.

Comment: Then that layout should be inflated in that window whether its a separate activity, dialog, popupWindow,etc... But you shouldn't be referencing them in this class. If its a dialog or popupwindow then you have to set the new layout with setView(), setLayout(), etc...

Comment: Somebody help me, I'm still stuck unfortunately :(

Comment: @Raghunandan could you explain how I could go about fixing the above code? I'm relatively new to android development, so I'm not really sure what you're saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your `DisplayMessageActivity` class. It appears you don't have a `onClick()` method. So when you click the `Button` it crashes. Since you have in your xml `android:onClick="onClick"`, you need a function in that class like

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
    // put code here
}
```

It looks like you misnamed your `EditText` unless this was a copy/paste error. You have

```
private EditText text;
```

But you initialiize

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
```

then you try to call a function on the uninitialized `text`

```
if(text.getText().length() == 0){
```

resulting in a `NPE`. I don't know if those are suppose to be two different ones but, either way, I don't see `text` initialized anywhere

Comment: I initialized it now, however I am still getting the error. And yes they are meant for two different edit texts.

Comment: Then you need to post the logcat so we can see what is causing the error and show where your `RadioButton`s are in the xml

Comment: @ironman2295 Put your `RadioButton`s in the `Layout` you inflate with `setContentView()`

Comment: I did do that, I have attached the second xml file above

Comment: No, you haven't. It is in a separate xml file than is set with `setContentView()` so `findViewById()` won't work because it only looks in the currently inflated xml file

Comment: Oh, my apologies then. Can you suggest a change because I'm currently really confused on what to add/where to add it.

Comment: It really just depends on what you are trying to do. I don't know if you want a new `Activity`, a `Dialog`, etc... I will be leaving in about 10 minutes and should be back in about 30. Get together what you are trying to do and I can try to help get you going if you haven't figured it out by then

Comment: I am indeed creating a new activity. That's what I was trying to do.  I'm not really sure what you mean by inflate though. I am googling these terms and trying to make sense of them as much as I can and I'm sorry if I sound foolish. So, in order to get the buttons to respond in the new activity, what do you advise I do next?

Comment: How would I go about inflating the layout in the separate activity?

Comment: You use `setContentView()` in the `onCreate()` of `DisplayMessageActivity`. Take your `RadioButton` references out of this `Activity` and put them in `DisplayMessageActivity`

Comment: My DisplayMessageActivity currently has this: protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
        // Make sure we're running on Honeycomb or higher to use ActionBar APIs
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            // Show the Up button in the action bar.
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }

 }

Comment: Post your logcat if you're still confused because I know I am

Comment: So do I just take out everything from inside the brackets of setContentView?

Comment: Just posted the logcat, or atleast what i could fit in the limit

Comment: I just moved the onlclick method from the main activity to display message activity, but the error still persists

Comment: The same error? If so clean your project, Project-->Clean then run it again and see if the logcat is the same or if you get different errors

Comment: Yeah it's the same error. Unfortunately "BCI-SNSApplication  has stopped working" I even cleaned the project.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31978/discussion-between-codemagic-and-ironman2295)